# How to efficiently step up high amperage source by just a few volts

Tags: boost, amperage, alternator

My car has an alternator that supplies 90A at 28V (it's a 24V vehicle). However, I have now fitted two AGM batteries in series, which like a higher (14.8V each) charging voltage. Therefore I would like to boost the voltage to the batteries to 29.6V (= 1.6V extra).

I know about step up converters and LDO's but these seem to generally work for relative low amperages, certainly not 90A.

Any idea how I can efficiently boost it by a few volts extra?

Thanks,
Sjoerd

Comment: I would have my doubts that you really need that extra few volts. Also if its a modern alternator it might be possible to modify it, as it contains some control circuitry for the voltage.

Comment: LDOs drop voltage, they don't boost them (i.e. the output of the regulator is lower than the input).

Comment: To be more precise, the alternator is a Lucas No.19 Mk.1 with a Prestolite 600-9 regulator. There is no way to tweak it. - I've been told that the specified output voltage might vary, so, it might actually provide a bit more than 28V.. I'm going to measure the output and report back here.

Answer (score 4):

Diddle the regulator to increase the setpoint slightly, the alternator itself will probably quite happily do 35+ volts is the field is at maximum, and the revs are not at minimum idle.

You don't say what car, what alternator and what alternator regulator...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a typical modern automotive charging system schematic, including the details of the voltage regulator which uses a [monolithic chip](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/CS3361-D.PDF).

[image]

The exact voltage at which is regulated is controlled by R2, which would be around 25K for a 24V system.

In some more modern cars you may be able to make the changes through a port- mine has profiles which can be programmed for various types of batteries.

Comment: Thanks, it's interesting to see this. Unfortunatly, my tech is quite outdated, see my comment above.